# javascript function to compare optionbox value with DIV tag

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I am new to javascript language and i have written this javascript function to compare the value of an HTML option box with content of a DIV tag but it is not working. What could be wrong please?

```
function marker(VarQuestion){
if (ans.VarQuestion == div.VarQuestion) {
div.VarQuestion . res = 1;
}else{
div.VarQuestion . res = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: what error r u getting?

Comment: it is not functioning as it should. div.VarQuestion.res is not showing either 1 or 0

Comment: could u jsfiddle ur code?

Comment: i don't understand the meaning of jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle.net add ur code here..

Comment: i just added my code to jsfiddle.net and nothing happen.

Comment: nothing will happen..its just to check ur output..hope u saved it and then ran the code??once done with that just post the link here..

Comment: i have saved it and i have ran it, yet no output